Network Device error in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (WSL2) when doing network setup with Powerscript
My company provides some network tweaking scripts to update the WSL network stack to work together with our internal network / corporate proxy / etc.
The part of the powerscript which is problematic in my case is here:
Write-Host "Attach static ip to the wsl2 interface"

    $ips = (wsl -d $wsl_distro -u root bash -c "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | cut -d ' ' -f6").Split("`n")
    $broadcasts = (wsl -d $wsl_distro -u root bash -c "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | cut -d ' ' -f8").Split("`n")
    # Remove all IPv4 addresses
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ips.length; $i++) {
        $current_ip = $ips[$i]
        # Don't touch IPv6
        if ($current_ip -notlike "*:*") {
            # If it's not the static WSL IP, it's the currently generated dynamic IP
            if ($current_ip.Split("/")[0] -ne $wsl_ip) {
                $dynamic_ip = $current_ip
                $dynamic_broadcast = $broadcasts[$i]
            }
            wsl -d $wsl_distro -u root ip addr del $current_ip dev eth0
        }
    }

This line here
 wsl -d $wsl_distro -u root ip addr del $current_ip dev eth0

gives me this error
RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied

A dedicated call gives me the same, of course (e.g
ip a del  169.254.228.65/32 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied

)
Here are some system data:
ip a
2: eth0: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 2c:58:b9:bf:89:f7
    inet 169.254.228.65/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e0fe:af6f:2cc2:4c2e/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 2c:58:b9:bf:89:f8
    inet 192.168.1.179/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 861500sec preferred_lft 861500sec
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: wifi0: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 f8:fe:5e:4b:ae:d3
    inet 169.254.114.60/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6413:12e6:8c8c:6e32/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: wifi1: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 f8:fe:5e:4b:ae:d4
    inet 169.254.245.78/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2eb5:6676:ff9:b064/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: wifi2: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 fa:fe:5e:4b:ae:d3
    inet 169.254.1.94/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::feab:6b73:55ca:a6a0/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1390 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:05:9a:3c:7a:00
    inet 10.130.35.250/18 brd 10.130.63.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Distribution:
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Anyone has an idea what I could try?
